# Why aren't globals copied when I run eval with a globals argument?

Tags: python, eval

I'm having difficulty understanding how `eval()` behaves regarding the globals used in the evaluated expression.

For example, the following script prints `1`:

```
x = 1
print eval('x')
```

While the following script fails on `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`:

```
x = 1
print eval('x', {})
```

However, from [the documentation of `eval()` for my Python version](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#eval) (emphasis mine):

> The *expression* argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression (technically speaking, a condition list) using the *globals* and *locals* dictionaries as global and local namespace. **If the *globals* dictionary is present and lacks ‘__builtins__’, the current globals are copied into *globals* before *expression* is parsed**.

So according to this, since a *globals* argument is present and indeed lacks `__builtins__`, I'd expect all the current globals - including `x` - to be copied into it before the expression is evaluated; but apparently that is not the case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. Whether it's a bug in the documentation or the implementation, I don't know, but `eval` does not copy the current globals into `globals` if `__builtins__` is not present. Rather, [it only copies `__builtins__`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#l655):

```
if (PyDict_GetItemString(globals, "__builtins__") == NULL) {
    if (PyDict_SetItemString(globals, "__builtins__",
                             PyEval_GetBuiltins()) != 0)
        return NULL;
}
```

I didn't find anything about this on the [Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/), and the discrepancy is still present in 3.4 and the current dev branch, so it may be worth submitting a bug report and a proposed documentation correction:

> If the *globals* dictionary is present and lacks ‘`__builtins__`’, the current `__builtins__` is copied into *globals* before *expression* is parsed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've [created a new issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue22057), as you have suggested.