# How does name binding work with eval()?

Tags: python, eval

I'm having difficulty understanding how name binding is done when using `eval()`. I'm using Python 2.7.3.

For example, I have defined the following:

```
x = 1

def foo():
  return x
```

The below snippet crashes on missing `x`, which indicates run-time name binding:

```
del x
print foo()
```

Now, since [providing a global dictionary to `eval()` overrides all other globals except `__builtins__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24934908/242762), I would also expect such a crash over `x` from the following line:

```
print eval('foo()', {'foo': foo})
```

However, that line runs fine and prints out `1`. **Why does that happen?**

And similarly, why does `print eval('foo()', {'foo': foo, 'x': 2})` print 1 and not 2?

Comment: Is `x: 2` a typo in your question? Otherwise, the dictionary you are passing uses the current value of `x` (1) as a key that maps to 2.

Comment: "which indicates run-time name binding" - no, it doesn't. Why would it?

Comment: @chepner it's a typo, fixed.

Comment: @user2357112 if there are two branches that call to `foo()`, one deleting `x` first and another not, then a crash over a missing variable will depend on the branch taken - I'd call this run-time name binding. Perhaps it's not the proper term for this?

Comment: Not quite binding; although the lookup is performed when the function is called, the place where that lookup *looks* is fixed when the function is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions always resolve names in the environment they were defined in, not the environment they were called in. When you insert `foo` into the `eval` call's globals, it still looks in its original environment's globals for `x` rather than the new environment. This is the same mechanism that lets you do

```
from some_file import foo
foo()
```

and have `foo` use `some_file.x` instead of trying to access the current scope's nonexistent `x`,

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm confused as to why `del x` would make `foo()` crash, could you clarify that?

Comment: Because `del x` deleted `x` from the same scope that `foo.func_global` references. `foo.func_globals` isn't a copy, it's a reference, and you executed `del x` in the same environment in which `foo` was defined.

Comment: @Oak: Are you expecting the function to always see its environment in the state it was when the function was defined? Or are you expecting the value of `x` to be substituted into the function at definition time, ignoring future changes? You deleted the `x` variable. The environment the function looks in for name resolution no longer contains that name.

Comment: OK, so looking up a name is done at runtime, but the environment in which it is looked up is the one the function was defined at. Thanks for the clarification, and also thanks @chepner.

Comment: One last example (contorted, to fit everything into a single expression to make `eval` happy) to show how you can manipulate the global scope of `foo`: `print eval('foo.func_globals.__setitem__("x", 6) or foo()', {'foo': foo})`.